# Not able to Mock "Insert Logs" Module in MuleSoft Munit

Tags: mule, mulesoft, munit

I am trying to mock below flow but getting below exception while run the test case.

**Error** : [module-alliant-logger.xml:52]: Cannot use error type 'ALLIANT-LOGGER:PARSING': namespace already exists.
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.core.api.config.ConfigurationException: [module-alliant-logger.xml:52]: Cannot use error type 'ALLIANT-LOGGER:PARSING': namespace already exists.

Munit Flow:

```
<munit:test name="munit-demo-test-suiteTest" doc:id="5133bc2a-1b4a-4efa-bc9e-a293bd3f0764" >
    <munit:behavior>
        <munit-tools:mock-when doc:name="Mock when transform" doc:id="b0513fbf-a209-494b-b39f-c5c20f69256a" processor="ee:transform">
            <munit-tools:with-attributes >
                <munit-tools:with-attribute whereValue="Transform Message" attributeName="doc:name" />
                <munit-tools:with-attribute whereValue="b228d101-a703-4824-8687-4da4f4792104" attributeName="doc:id" />
            </munit-tools:with-attributes>
            <munit-tools:then-return >
                <munit-tools:payload value='#[%dw 2.0&#10;output application/json&#10;---&#10;{&#10;    "ErrorSource" : "Unknown-ErrorSource",&#10; "ErrorDescription":"Unknown-ErrorDescription"&#10;}]' mediaType="application/json" />
            </munit-tools:then-return>
        </munit-tools:mock-when>
        <munit-tools:mock-when doc:name="Mock when : logger:insert-logs" doc:id="86d27f7c-5560-4094-8b3b-3435e08122e3" processor="alliant-logger:insert-logs">
            <munit-tools:with-attributes >
                <munit-tools:with-attribute whereValue="5bc0671a-6ccf-4ac0-8077-94e918f50c44" attributeName="doc:id" />
                <munit-tools:with-attribute whereValue="Alliant_logger_Config" attributeName="config-ref" />
            </munit-tools:with-attributes>
            <munit-tools:then-return >
                <munit-tools:payload value="Success" mediaType="application/octet-stream" />
                <munit-tools:attributes value='#[{&#10;  "headers": {&#10;    "content-type": "application/json",&#10;    "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.36.1",&#10;    "accept": "*/*",&#10;    "cache-control": "no-cache",&#10;    "postman-token": "c30d4d25-4bf0-4dd8-b118-addddbabae35",&#10;    "host": "localhost:8083",&#10;    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",&#10;    "connection": "keep-alive",&#10;    "content-length": "69"&#10;  },&#10;  "clientCertificate": null,&#10;  "method": "POST",&#10;  "scheme": "http",&#10;  "queryParams": {},&#10;  "requestUri": "/api/Create",&#10;  "queryString": "",&#10;  "version": "HTTP/1.1",&#10;  "maskedRequestPath": "/Create",&#10;  "listenerPath": "/api/*",&#10;  "relativePath": "/api/Create",&#10;  "localAddress": "/127.0.1.1:8083",&#10;  "uriParams": {},&#10;  "rawRequestUri": "/api/Create",&#10;  "rawRequestPath": "/api/Create",&#10;  "remoteAddress": "/127.0.1.1:55537",&#10;  "requestPath": "/api/Create"&#10;}]' />
            </munit-tools:then-return>
        </munit-tools:mock-when>
    </munit:behavior>
    <munit:execution>
        <munit:set-event doc:name="Set Event" doc:id="ec2d7f54-dcf9-4a46-ba45-aa7a5952be0d">
            <munit:payload value='#[%dw 2.0&#10;output application/json&#10;---&#10;{&#10;  "ErrorSource": "Source",&#10;  "ErrorDescription": "Description"&#10;}]' mediaType="application/json" />
        </munit:set-event>
        <flow-ref doc:name="Flow Reference" doc:id="e306b636-d827-4d51-a7b1-28e2730200a0" name="munit-demoFlow1"/>
    </munit:execution>
    <munit:validation>
        <munit-tools:assert-that doc:name="Assert that" doc:id="c7e2f3d0-fdfb-4f63-95ec-a97bf3f5b50e" expression="#[payload]" is="#[MunitTools::notNullValue()]"/>
    </munit:validation>
</munit:test>
```

Below showing Main flow, I want to mock. I have created one separate Mule Application to log error. Now, that application use as module (dependency) in this Demo. "Insert Log"

```
<flow name="munit-demoFlow1"
    doc:id="945f8d10-a965-46ef-a2a8-8156afe41965">
    <http:listener doc:name="Listener"
        doc:id="767336a9-5a33-4913-b55e-41f94f7a6625"
        config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/LoggerTesting" />
    <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message"
        doc:id="b228d101-a703-4824-8687-4da4f4792104">
        <ee:message>
            <ee:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    "ErrorSource" : "Unknown-ErrorSource",
    "ErrorDescription":"Unknown-ErrorDescription"
}]]></ee:set-payload>
        </ee:message>
    </ee:transform>
    <alliant-logger:insert-logs
        doc:name="Insert Logs" doc:id="5bc0671a-6ccf-4ac0-8077-94e918f50c44"
        config-ref="Alliant_logger_Config" />
    <set-payload doc:name="Set Payload"
        doc:id="94400a58-db42-4a7e-b4db-42a2242d508b"
        value="#[%dw 2.0&#10;output application/java&#10;---&#10;if(payload as String == 'Success' as String) &#10; 'its working'&#10;else&#10; 'its not working']" />
</flow>
```

Below request/response passing in "Insert Log".
[image: Insert-log]

Alliant logger as module.

[image: Alliant Logger]

I am using localhost URL to access it. I run two application parallel so, its working fine.
[image: Alliant Logger Configuration]

I know that, Error throw from "Insert Log" but not able to figure-out that why its occurring. I am not able to debug the test case because of this error. if I comment "Insert Log" then its working fine but I want to Mock "Insert Log".

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). Instead add the XML text of the flow and the details of the request as text. Which versions of Mule and MUnit are you using?

Comment: Which line is module-alliant-logger.xml:52?

Comment: @aled, MUnit : 3.0.0 and Mule : 4.5

Comment: On 52 line number : <http:request config-ref="alliant-logger-httpreq-config" path="/Create" method="POST" requestStreamingMode='#[vars["request-streaming-mode"]]' >

Comment: You haven't shared that flow. Please edit the question to add details.

Comment: Still there is not enough information to understand the issue. The file with the error is not shared. More log lines may be needed for context. The Maven pom.xml may also be needed. Is there any raise-error component with  ALLIANT-LOGGER:PARSING anywhere in the application or the connector?

Comment: Is module-alliant-logger a connector created with the XML SDK?

Comment: @aled, No Module-alliant-logger not created with xml sdk or Mule SDK. its first created in API designer then public into exchange. Then in new mule application, I have added as Module.

Comment: @aled, I am not using raise-error component anywhere in the application or the connector.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same error with connectors mocking in MUnit.
"Cannot use error type 'xxxxxxx:PARSING': namespace already exists."
In Mule Runtime 4.4 is no problem, but the error occurs in 4.5 and 4.6.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: can you provide some supportive info with your answer. please check this- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I reported this to the MuleSoft Support and they identified this as a bug.

https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000yCg1q/error-namespace-already-exists-when-running-munit-tests-on-runtime-451-or-452